# Tabela com array de dados

Tags: node.js, react, next.js

Por que a tabela só aparece dados se definir a posição do elemento no array?

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Table } from 'reactstrap'
import axios from 'axios'

import Menu from '../components/Menu'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'


const AreaTematica = (data) => (
    <div>
        <Head>
            <title>Áreas Temáticas</title>
            <meta name='robots' content='index, follow' />
            <meta name='description' content='Módulo de Áreas Temáticas' />
        </Head>
        <Menu />
        <Table striped>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                
                <tr>
                    <td>{data.response.areatematica.docs[0]._id}</td>
                    <td>{data.response.areatematica.docs[0].nome}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    </div>
)

AreaTematica.getInitialProps = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/areastematicas')
    return { response: response.data }
}

export default AreaTematica
```

Comment: fiquei na dúvida do que vc quer fazer. 
A resposta que vc recebe do axios é um array, e você quer que cada item do array seja uma linha na tabela?

Comment: isso mesmo. cada item numa linha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver.
No

`return {response: response.data}`

acrescentei areastematicas.docs, ficou assim:

`return {response: response.data.areastematicas.docs}`

Answer (score 0):

Parece que os dados então vindo em array...

é por isso que você precisa dizer a posição. Se for um array de dados mesmo o que você quer, você deve percorrer esse array ...

```
renderRows() {
        return array.map(d => {
            return (
                <tr key={d.id}>
                    <td>{d.id}</td>
                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
```

depois pode chamar o metodo dentro da tag

```
<tbody>
{this.renderRows()}
</tbody>
```

claro, você você deve fazer as adaptações necessárias. no lugar do array deve ser esse seu array que vem do axios

Comment: Onde colocaria este `renderRows()` para percorrê-lo?

Comment: <tbody>
{this.renderRows()}
</tbody>

Comment: Digo este código:`renderRows() {
        return array.map(d => {
            return (
                <tr key={d.id}>
                    <td>{d.id}</td>
                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }`

Comment: Isso é um metodo. Crie o metodo, coloque ele em algum lugar e chame no tbody.
pode ser ate em outro arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

crie o metodo em algum lugar e chame do tbody. Pode ser em outro arquivo component.

```
renderRows() {
        return array.map(d => {
            return (
                <tr key={d.id}>
                    <td>{d.id}</td>
                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
```

se quiser component de classe, seque o exemplo (que eu acho melhor)

https://github.com/TXTDBR/react-crud/blob/master/src/components/user/RenderTable.jsx